# How to have an interactive map in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to use an image of a map that the user can hover over and select a US State that I will then use for another part of my program, how would I do this?

Comment: What is your approach so far?
Any code to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get a map of the United States
2. Draw it on a JPanel
3. Add a click handler to the JPanel
4. In the click handler, retrieve information where the user clicked from the event
5. Have a set of polygons of all the state boundaries
6. Iterate through all the poloygons to check if the user clicked inside one
7. Return the associated state